# How to have a div as a box not span past/off the screen

Tags: html, css

I have the following block of code for the styling on a div supposed to be a box:

```
.newsBox{
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: medium;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

I am using this code in a PWA, and so it is going to be used on a mobile screen.

Instead of my div just spanning the entire screen of my phone, it spans off the screen as well (and so I have to move the screen left and right to view the whole box), but I can't understand why when my width is set to 100%. I have tried everything I could find on stack overflow and other websites; I think it may just be my code that's wrong.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: tried `width: 100vw;`?

Comment: @ArunAS yes I have tried it, but it makes it worse than using 100%. When I use 100vw, it doesn't let me move the screen up or down, and I don't know why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After setting the the width to 100% and adding extra padding, it will show annoying scrollbars. Try to add the `box-sizing: border-box;` property to your div and it will be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Without the `box-sizing` property, an element with padding will actually be bigger than its width and height. You should try the following:

```
.newsBox{
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: medium;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

You can read more about box sizing [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp).

Aditionally you must take into account the width of your newsBox's parent container. Setting newsBox's `width` to 100% means it will be full width *within its parent*.

Answer (score 1):

The scroll probably appear because there is `margin` or `padding` property set up somewhere (browsers add them to html and body by default). You can turn it off with:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

`box-sizing` changes the way browser calculate the width of the element ( 100% - padding of the parent is used instead of 100%).

But it is hard to guess without an actual code.

Comment: Would it be more useful for me to post all of my `style.css` for people to see?

Comment: @AliMosallaei to be honest style.css is not enough, if the issue is a horizontal scroll on mobile everything on the page can cause it - and it is hard to guess without checking. So at least HTML + CSS is required (images can force scroll to).

Comment: Ok, I will try to edit my question and add the HTML File the CSS goes with.